# SignInManager could not be found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I cannot use SignInManager as it is not found.

I have checked countless pages about this but there does not seem to be a clear answer.

My .csproj looks like this;

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Domain\Domain.csproj"/>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Persistence\Persistence.csproj"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.0.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

What do I need to do to be able to use SignInManager [image]

Comment: Add reference `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;`

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you are trying to use this SignInManager:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The documentation states it is a part of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll`,
so you might need installing the corresponding NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note:

In .NET 8, `SignInManager` is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI